# unable to verify the first certificate when running npm install

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu, ssl

I'm was looking at the Angular2 tutorial on:
https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/README.md

However, when I run the npm install as per the guide, i initially got an error related to `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`.
Which on googling seemed related to SSL cert so I then attempted to just get around this by using the following command:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

I then retried `npm install`

This got a bit further but then got new errors related to "unable to verify the first certificate":

> ```
> typings ERR! message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/core-js/tags/0.0.0%2B20160725163759"
> typings ERR! caused by unable to verify the first certificate
>
> typings ERR! cwd c:\Code\Angular2\Quickstart
> typings ERR! system Windows_NT 6.1.7601
> typings ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Code\\Angular2\\Quickstart\\node_modules\\typings\\dist\\bin.js" "install"
> typings ERR! node -v v6.7.0
> typings ERR! typings -v 1.4.0
> typings ERR! code EUNAVAILABLE
>
> typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
> typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
>
> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
> npm WARN angular-quickstart@1.0.0 No license field.
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
> npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
> npm ERR! node v6.7.0
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall: `typings install`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall script 'typings install'.
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR!     typings install
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
> npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     c:\Code\Angular2\Quickstart\npm-debug.log
> ```

I'm new to NodeJS and Angular2 development. Any ideas ?
If I have missed out any detail then let me know.

Comment: If you google `npm EUNAVAILABLE` you get a lot of errors with typings.  You could try installing typings manually.  e.g. `npm install typings -g --msvs-version=2015` which just worked for me.

Comment: p.s. i'm still on node 4.2.3

Comment: @leetibbett I tried that suggestion then re-ran the same npm install command but stil got the same error

Comment: So the manual global install of typings worked or failed?

Comment: @leetibbett "npm install typings -g --msvs-version=2015" worked but when i run "npm install" I still get the original error related to ceritficates

Comment: Try to install it locally not globally by removing the `-g` from the manual command above, like `npm install typings --msvs-version=2015`

Comment: Ok tried this and still the same error, presumably to do this I just run "npm install typings --msvs-version=2015"

Comment: so actually it fails.  do you have a http proxy?  did you configure it in npm config?

Comment: @leetibbett hi yes, I believe we are behind a company proxy but don't have much detail about from that in IE, under connections I can see a path to a script under automatic configuration script. So I haven't conigured the npm config but I didn't realise the proxy was an issue some of the packages do seem to have been installed from what I can see in node_modules

Comment: If you download the autoconfig script with your web browser and look at it, it should contain the proxy name.  From there you can configure it into npm with `npm config set proxy=http://<proxy>:<port>`.  You might also need to configure git which I think is like `git configure --add http.proxy http://<proxy>:<port>`

Comment: Actually, going through the script, it seems to for all bar certain sites just allow websites to be accessed directly but I think there is some kind of proxy in use as some sites are restricted based on content but not sure how this is being done. Regardless, do I need to configure git or npm still as for e.g. I'm still able to access git as was the case when i ran the git clone to get the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using the instructions here:
https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/564

The issue is ultimately related to my machine being behind some corporate proxy which seems to be related to npm unable to authenticate https against the proxy.
Since I didn't have any further information about the proxy being used so was unable to configure as per @leetibbett suggestion above. 
So I created .typingsrc file in the root directory to use http version:

```
{
     "rejectUnauthorized": false,
     "registryURL": "http://api.typings.org/"
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can try change the registry to the http version in config

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ --global
```

Comment: After setting this, i am seeing the same issue,  as npm is trying to install the following and failing again. message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/node/tags/****

Comment: I tried to access using a browser https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/node/tags/ and I have got this message: Cannot GET /entries/dt/node/tags/

Comment: Use the method supplied by @Rubans. It worked for me.

Comment: It worked after running the npm config above. I was able to create a new app using the "create-react-app".

Answer (score 15):

In my case adding the ca-file in .npmrc to the corporate proxy certificate was the solution:

```
npm config set cafile "path to proxy cert file"
```

or insert with editor in .npmrc:

```
cafile=<path to proxy cert file>
```

The .npmrc file is located in the home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Set environment variable **NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED** to **0**.

Comment: what are the larger implications of doing this? Are there security concerns?

Comment: @starball __NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED__ set to __0__ means that node.js is not verifying that the SSL/TLS certificates have a proper and unbroken path up to a trusted "root" certificate. Only use it when you get a "unable to verify the first certificate" during npm install process, and the source of the package you will install must be trusted. After the package installed, delete this environment variable.

Comment: is this question not a duplicate of the one that you posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76447868/11107541) to?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the node Js 12 and reinstalled the version 10. That solved my problem. I am not sure if the problem was the version, but you can try. I hope that has helped you.