# unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, https

Why is this error coming? Someone can tell me What is the solution for this? And if I create a new project with the npm init command. **UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE** error in running

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to verify the first certificate when running npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000952/unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-when-running-npm-install)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can use this command

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

> It just disabled SSL certificates.
>
> But it's not a best practice to accept invalid SSL certificate.
>
> you can revert it later with this command

```
npm config set strict-ssl true
```

Answer (score 2):

Set environment variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` to `0`.

`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` set to `0` means that node.js is not verifying that the SSL/TLS certificates have a proper and unbroken path up to a trusted "root" certificate.

**Only use it** when you get a "unable to verify the first certificate" during npm install process, and the source of the package you will install must be trusted. After the package installed, delete this environment variable.