# Resize image before saving with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have an upload function like this :

```
app.post("/upload", function (req, res) {
  let base64 = req.body.image.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
  binaryData = Buffer.from(base64, "base64").toString("binary");

  fs.writeFile(
    "./pictures/" + Date.now() + ".png",
    binaryData,
    "binary",
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );

  fs.writeFile(
    "./thumbnails/" + Date.now() + ".png",
    binaryData,
    "binary",
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
```

The first part saves image into "pictures" folder.
That works ok, nothing to do here.

The second parts saves the same image into "thumbnails" folder.
**What I need to do is to resize the image before its saved, to have only resized images in that folder.**

Comment: You will probably want to include some image manipulation library for that

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Sharp library: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize

```
app.post("/upload", function (req, res) {
let base64 = req.body.image.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
binaryData = Buffer.from(base64, "base64").toString("binary");

fs.writeFile(
    "./pictures/" + Date.now() + ".png",
    binaryData,
    "binary",
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
);

sharp(binaryData)
    .resize({ width: 100 })
    .toBuffer()
    .then(data => {
        // 100 pixels wide, auto-scaled height
        fs.writeFile(
            "./thumbnails/" + Date.now() + ".png",
            data,
            "binary",
            function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
        )
    })
})
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. But I can't install sharp with npm. I get this error : Installation error: unable to verify the first certificate.
I tried to do npm install sharp --unsafe-perms but nothing changes.

Comment: Refer to other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000952/unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-when-running-npm-install

Comment: This only worked for me after some adjustments, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Guille Sanchez answer, I needed to do some adjustments to make it work:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
let base64 = req.body.image.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, '');

//using buffer instead of binary
buffer = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64');

fs.writeFile(
 './pictures/' + Date.now() + '.png',
 buffer,
 // using utf8 instead of binary
 'utf8',
 function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    }
  }
 );

//using buffer instead of binary
sharp(buffer)
.resize({ width: 100 })
.toBuffer()
.then((data) => {
  // 100 pixels wide, auto-scaled height
  fs.writeFile(
    './thumbnails/' + Date.now() + '.png',
    data,
    //using utf8 instead of binary
    'utf8',
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
 });
});
```